# Impact on dividend on a autocall

Tags: derivatives

Can someone explain me the impact of the dividends on an autocall structure please ?
Is it going to increase the price because of the Short PDI in the structure ?

Comment: What kind of "autocall structure" are you referring to? I assume you mean PDI = put down&in, so some sort of barrier reverse convertible?

Comment: a classic autocall what will be the impact of the dividends from the underlying if it happens